# Chrome no longer opens up PDFs

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

Wondering if anyone who has experienced this and know a fix.

When your download a pdf that gets opened on chrome, it's a blank page. This is only happening on my computer I have tested this on my laptop and it was okay.

I have gone to chrome://plugins to verify the settings are good.

The one thing I believe it's problem with the software is because 1 out of 5 times I can refresh my page and the pdf will load. There is nothing wrong with the server serving the pdf.

Is there a way where I can "repair" chrome?

Comment: Do you have an example link to a PDF this happens with that we can test?

Comment: @ode2k http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~oommen/Courses/COMP4106Winter16/BayesClassifiers.pdf

Comment: What OS / Version are you using?

Comment: I'm seeing precisely the same issue on version 79.0.3945.79 for Linux. pdfs only show up about 1 in 5 refreshes. Oddly, I can't reproduce the problem in an incognito window, even though I have all extensions disabled. Turning off hardware acceleration did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be related to:

[Chromium Issue 594343](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=594343&q=PDF&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

**Disable GPU Rendering (PC / Mac)**

**Chrome** -> **Settings** --> Click the **Show advanced settings...** Link at the bottom

[image: Chrome Settings]

---

[image: Advanced Settings]

---

[image: Hardware Acceleration Setting]

Scroll to the bottom under the **System** section and uncheck the box to **Use hardware acceleration when available**

Then close your browser, reopen and try again.

Then try opening the PDF file again.

Answer (score -1):

Try to update chrome. The problem was known, and corrected in the version 46.0.2490.80m.

See this for more info :

> https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543018